# ssh: connect to host **.***.***.*** port 22: Operation Timed Out

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean

I have VPS on digitalocean. But I have no access to the account where my server created. Because I didn't created droplet myself. I asked somebody. And now I can't access my server. I contacted digitalocean, but no answer yet. Any idea. Please help.

```
ssh root@ip-adress
```

It returns this error:
ssh: connect to host **.**.**.*** port 22: Operation Timed Out

Comment: Sorry, of topic here. And, most likely the only people that will be able to help you are those running those servers.

Comment: @GhostCat won't digital ocean help if I give password?

Comment: Though luck then. But what do you expect?

Comment: @GhostCat just reboot my server

Comment: And how do you think that anybody else could be doing that? And the fact that you can't login does not mean that your server is done. Many systems are configured to not allow root to log in remotely.

Comment: @GhostCat but I was accessing it yesterday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try login using username/password instead SSH.

<kbd>Launch Console</kbd> then, login with root/. If you don't know the password of `root` user then, reset your root password. Digital Ocean will mail to admin account for resetting the root password.

[image]

After login successfully, add your Public Key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) into the droplet. Afer that you would allow login using SSH.

If none of these works for you then, ask somebody else (who has the access in the Droplet) to add your Public Key in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file of the Droplet machine.

Comment: I know root password I was accessing my server yesterday. I know root password. But I have no access to the account in digitalocean

Comment: "I have no access to the account in digitalocean" so, you are not able to login in DO account? or login into a specific droplet? `ssh root@ip-adress` looks like you are trying to login in a specific droplet.

Comment: to the specific droplet

Comment: Ok. If you were able to login previously and can't login now then, maybe somehow your Public Key is deleted from `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. Add the Public key again in the *known_hosts* file.

Comment: i cant't login from local terminal but i can access via droplet console , but when i write ~/.ssh/known_hosts OR ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
i get no such file or directory

Answer (score 5):

Might be caused by a rule in "UFW", https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

If so, enable port 20 - this should help

```
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
```